# Returning the member in a group with the highest of a specific property

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to find the process with the highest CPU in a given group, in my case the group is simply by `processname`. Assume I have these processes running:

```
  Id ProcessName           CPU       Memory Threads
  -- -----------           ---       ------ -------
  7532 MicrosoftEdgeCP   40,3125 355,51953125      27
  1680 powershell_ise     47,875  214,1015625      23
  7568 lync               7,9375   213,859375      52
  9664 chrome           19,71875  167,9609375      12
  4216 MicrosoftEdgeCP 92,578125  152,2890625      26
  5392 explorer         31,09375   116,390625      66
  2676 chrome          23,390625    110,96875      41
  9812 chrome             14,625   100,859375       8
  2872 MsMpEng                    100,5234375      36
  5752 SearchUI         2,609375      90,0625      23
```

I'm trying to find Chrome (9664). Currently I have this code:

```
$list = @()

$grouped = Get-Process | Where ProcessName -Like "c*" | 
            Sort CPU -Descending | 
            Group ProcessName | 
            Select $_ -First 10 

$grouped

foreach($item in $grouped) {

    $list += @($item.Group | 
        Sort CPU -Descending |
        Select Id, ProcessName, CPU, Memory, Threads -First 1)
}

$list | ft -Wrap
```

Is it possible to do the same without storing the first in each group in the `$list` array?

Comment: `Get-Process | Where ProcessName -Like "c*" | 
            Sort CPU -Descending | 
            Group ProcessName | Foreach-object{$_.Group | Select -First 1}`? It is already sorted. No need to repeat that.

Comment: In your example are you not trying to match PID 2676  for chrome?

Comment: I'm not 100% on the title change. Needed to remove the tag at least from the title. Reword if you would like but don't roll back.

Comment: @Matt: your are right, my intention was not to retrieve only "Chrome"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you wanted to get the process where the CPU is the highest among the threads of the same name correct?

```
Get-Process -Name "c*" | 
    Sort-Object CPU -Descending | 
    Group ProcessName | 
    ForEach-Object{$_.Group | Select Id, ProcessName, CPU, Memory, Threads -First 1}
```

`-Name` supports wildcards so we can save returning all the processes just to drop most of them. Do the first sort and group on `processname`. Then just take the first entry from each individual group. The last for each is required to prevent the object array from being unrolled and only returning the highest overall entry.